# WARN unable to find package.json for plottable

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops, storybook

When running a build for storybook via an Azure devops pipeline I get the above mentioned error.

I've tried to completely remove this package(plottable) from my project but I keep getting this error and it causes my webpack build to get stuck.

This error doesn't occur locally.

My pipeline:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - master

stages:
- stage: develop_build_deploy_stage
  pool:
    name: Default
    demands:
      - msbuild
      - visualstudio
      
  jobs:
  - job: develop_build_deploy_job
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      clean: true
      persistCredentials: true
        
    - task: NodeTool@0
      displayName: Install Node    
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '12.x'

    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Install Dependencies'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          npm install

    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Increment version'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          git checkout master
          git pull origin master
          git config --global user.email "d@gmail.com"
          git config --global user.name "Build Agent"
          npm version patch -m "Increment Version [skip ci]" --force
          git push

    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Build Project'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          npm run build-storybook
          npm run build

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy storybook-static Files'
      inputs:
        sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/storybook-static'
        contents: '**'
        targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish storybook-static Files to ArtifactStagingDirectory'
      inputs:
        pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        artifactName: Storybook

    - task: S3Upload@1
      displayName: 'Upload storybook-static to S3'
      inputs:
        awsCredentials: 'my-s3'
        regionName: 'us-east-1'
        bucketName: 'my-s3-bucket'
        sourceFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'Publish to Feed'
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        publishRegistry: 'useFeed'
        publishFeed: '#####'
```

How would I go about resolving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what caused this to be the case but for some reason the changes I had made on my branch weren't being picked up and an import that I had removed wasn't removed on the branch that was being built on.

So in the end it was trying to import a package which I had removed as a dependency.

Comment: Did you make the changes on master branch or other branch?

Comment: I made the change on the branch I was trying to build off.

I had to commit to master and then build off the master branch.

Comment: If you want to build another branch other than master branch. The yaml file should exist in that branch too with trigger including itself.